# Count occurrences of a string, by row, in a large data frame

Tags: r, count, summarize, rowsum

I am trying to count a binary character outcome by row in a large data frame:

```
V1      V2      V3      V4      V5  
Loss    Loss    Loss    Loss    Loss
Loss    Loss    Win     Win     Loss
Loss    Loss    Loss    Loss    Loss
```

Reprex:

```
df <- data.frame(
V1=c("Loss", "Loss", "Loss"),
V2=c("Loss", "Loss", "Loss"),
V3=c("Loss", "Win", "Loss"),
V4=c("Loss", "Win", "Loss"),
V5=c("Loss", "Loss", "Loss"))
```

What I need to know is the frequency of wins and losses by row. This is just a short example (fragment of large simulated output) but for row 1, in five simulations, I have five Losses, row two three loss and two win, etc.

I was hoping to generate either a separate table that shows the frequency of wins/loss by row or, if that won't work, add two new columns: one that provides the number of "Win" and "Loss" for each row.

Each row is a different case, and each column is a replicate of that case.  This appears as a data frame of factors with two levels "Loss" "Win".

Answer (score 13):

Here's a quick vectorized solution (assuming your data set called `df`)

```
Loss <- rowSums(df == "Loss") # Count the "Loss" per row
cbind(Loss, Wins = ncol(df) - Loss) # Subscribe these from the columns numbers and combine
#      Loss Wins
# [1,]    5    0
# [2,]    3    2
# [3,]    5    0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it was an easy solution, I was trying to make it much more complicated.  That worked nicely!

Comment: @mike: Consider accepting the answer than (and upvoting those answers which helped). That's the proper way to thank on SO. (might also flag this as obsolete after reading it...)

Comment: @mike this works because `==` finds TRUE/FALSE and `rowSums` coerces those values to 1/0, respectively. Try it: `sum(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)`.

Comment: Neat, but won't work when NAs are present. You'd need `cbind(Loss = rowSums(df=="Loss"), Wins = rowSums(df=="Win"))`

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative with base `R`:

```
stats = function(u){
    win = sum(u=="Win")
    data.frame(Win=win, Loss=length(u)-win)
}

Reduce(rbind, apply(df, 1, stats))

#  Win Loss
#1   0    5
#2   2    3
#3   0    5
```

Or even better in one line but non vectorized:

```
t(apply(df, 1, function(u) table(factor(u, levels=c("Win","Loss")))))

#     Win Loss
#[1,]   0    5
#[2,]   2    3
#[3,]   0    5
```

Comment: yes, unfortunately I did not manage to add a column to contingency table made with table :p Hence a solution with dplyr.

Comment: I don't think that `ldply` is from `dplyr` :) All you using here is base R + `plyr` + `magrittr`

Comment: %>% is in dplyr as well ;) but true, I forgot the plyr import!

Comment: Nope, it's from `magrittr`. `dplyr` is just masking it from there. Also, this solution would be extremely inefficient (no offence), even the double loop above will be more efficient than this one.

Comment: Oh ok. I went back base R, too sad there I do not know a function counting specified elements in a vector.

Comment: That base solution of your is nice, have a +1 :)

Comment: where did I put my head today!